# Excel: Create sum of list, data validation drop-down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I sum all the cells of a given category, created with Data Validation List? In Microsoft Office Excel 2011.

Example: In the C column, sum every value from that is found from the G column.

[image: Screenshot]

In Google Spreadsheet, I can do this with this formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(F3),"",SUM(FILTER($G$3:G,$F$3:F=B3)))`

But in Microsoft Excel it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `SUMIF` formula in Excel. and if you need multiple criteria you can use the `SUMIFS` formula.

The Excel equivalent would be something like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(F3),"",SUMIF($F$3:$F$100000,B3,$G$3:$G$100000))
```

Comment: It adds "100" in the result cell, additionally. So, if I have 500+500, the result is 1100.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I had a cell with "100" there that added this. This works, thanks!